# Metodologia de creacion de tabla MySQL para valores repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql

quiero hacerles una consulta sobre que es mas efectivo en un caso en particular. Por ejemplo, tengo estas tablas:

[image: Base]

Los valores de turno serian "MAÑANA, TARDE Y NOCHE" mi pregunta va en este sentido, es necesario crear una tabla aparte (como esta ahora) para almacenar solo esos 3 valores e integrarlos como una clave foranea, en ves de repetirlos en la tabla "tarea_correctivo" como un varchar? (no me interesa que sea enum)

Gracias.

Comment: Sí, es mejor tenerlo separado por tres motivos principales: **espacio**, imagina que la tabla tendrá millones de filas... no es lo mismo millones de VARCHAR que millones de TINYINT o de CHAR(1); **mantenimiento**, un usuario desprevenido podría escribir `TRDE` y miles errores parecidos... imagina lo que supondría mantener, imagina si buscas un WHERE columna='TARDE' y hay valores erróneos; **flexibilidad**, con tablas separadas el modelo se adapta con menos traumas a evoluciones futuras, por ejemplo la creación de un turno nuevo llamado `MADRUGADA` o que 1 misma tarea pueda tener varios turnos

Comment: Concuerdo con el comentario anterior, como un alcance adicional diría que también beneficia que crees una tabla nueva por temas de control y normalización. Osea... si en algún momento necesitases agregar otro turno, "madrugada" por ejemplo, bastaría con añadirlo a la nueva tabla y ya estaría cargado y validado en tu sistema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a mencionar sólo tres motivos importantes y demostrables por los que deberías tener una tabla aparte, tal y como lo tienes ahora:

1. **Integridad/Mantenimiento/Control de errores**: esta razón es suficiente para tener una tabla aparte. Si manejas el dato repitiéndolo una y otra vez te expones a miles o millones de posibles errores como: `TRDE`, `TARD`, `TARDF`, `MANANA`, `MÑANA`, `NOCHHE` ... y sigue contando.  Ninguno de esos datos erróneos aparecerá cuando hagas consultas como `WHERE turno = 'TARDE'`. En cualquier sistema el virus más peligroso de controlar es el usuario cuando agarra un teclado... y nuestra generación se caracteriza por los errores ortográficos. Veo al menos uno casi diario en lo único que veo en la TV (el telediario o noticias como dicen en América) y hablo de un país desarrollado: España.
2. **Flexibilidad**: tener una tabla aparte soportará con menos traumas cualquier evolución del modelo de datos. Imaginemos que posteriormente una tarea pueda realizarse en varios turnos. Habría que crear una nueva tabla llamada por ejemplo  `tareas_turnos`, trasladar a esa nueva tabla el `id_tarea` y el `id_turno` de cada fila  y a partir de ahí seguir manteniendo el nuevo modelo de datos sin demasiadas complicaciones.
3. **Espacio**: Supongamos que se trata de una tabla destinada a almacenar millones de filas. No es lo mismo tener millones de `VARCHAR` que millones de `TINYINT` o millones de `CHAR(1)`.

Quizá haya más motivos, pero creo que estos tres son suficientes para ver con claridad que conviene tener una tabla separada.

Comment: Formidable tu respuesta. Muchas gracias.